# What is the coproduct: A + A?

Tags: type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

In the HoTT book, it is said

> The type of booleans *2 : U* is intended to have exactly two elements. It is clear that we could construct this type out of coproduct and unit types as **1 + 1**.

I don't see how this works, since it seems to me **A + A = A**, which would imply **1 + 1 = 1**, and **1 != 2**. What am I missing?  (Sorry for the brevity; I'm only able to work and read using a mobile device for this week).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coproduct is the *disjoint* union. Set-theoretically, you can think of forming the coproduct of the sets $A$ and $B$ as:

$$
 A + B \;\;\triangleq\;\; \{ (0, a) \;|\; a \in A \} \cup \{ (1, b) \;|\; b \in B \}
$$

Now it should be obvious that $A + A \not= A$.

Comment: Thanks, I see now; "disjoint unions" were also used to describe dependent pair types, but I guess in that case there is a judgementally defined dependence on the second element, whereas for coproducts it is a simple label that is applied.